# How can I transform mouse Input into Touch Input in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this lines of code that work with mouse input: when mouse is pressed and moved up, the game object rotate, and when moved down, rotate backwards. I want to do the same but with my finger touch for an AR app. Please someone help me!!!

case "BOTAO GIRO (1)":

```
                if(botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 100)
                {
                    botao.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * speed);
                }else { }

                if(botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 350)
                {
                    botao.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * speed);
                }else { }

                if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                {

                    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") > 0)
                    {
                        if (botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 100 && botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 350)
                        {
                            Debug.Log(botao.transform.eulerAngles.z);
                            botao.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * speed);
                           
                        }
                      
                        
                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") < 0)
                        {
                            if (botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 100 && botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 350)
                            {
                                Debug.Log(botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
                                botao.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * speed);
                                
                            }
                            
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) == false)
                    {

                        eixo.SetActive(false);


                    }
                }
             

                break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In API e.g. [`Touch.phase`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html) where you can find a complete implementation example.

For you it would look somewhat like e.g.

```
private Vector2 firstTouchPosition;


...

case "BOTAO GIRO (1)":  
    if(botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 100)
    {
        botao.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * speed);
    }
    if(botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 350)
    {
        botao.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * speed);
    }

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        switch(touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                firstTouchPosition = touch.position;
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                var dif = touch.position - firstTouchPosition;
                if (dif.y > 0)
                {
                    if (botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 100 && botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 350)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(botao.transform.eulerAngles.z);
                        botao.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * speed);
                       
                    }                   
                    else if (did.y < 0)
                    {
                        if (botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 100 && botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 350)
                        {
                            Debug.Log(botao.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
                            botao.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * speed);           
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          exio.SetActive(false);
      }
```

---

**Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear**

Comment: That works really fine!!! Thank you so much! You rules!!! :D